# best place to add an action when application starts up or returns to the forground

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I need my application to do 2 network calls when ever the app is started for the 1st time, when it has been killed and started again as well as when it has been placed in the background then returned.

I know I can put it in my "MainActivity" onCreate/onResume. I have a class that extends Application which is where I am initialising logging and crash reporting, but I noticed there is no onResume method, which from my understand is the method that is called when the application comes from the background.

Where would be the best place to do these 2 network calls to update certain aspects in my app when the app is started for the 1st time, started when killed and resumed when it comes back from the background.

FYI. The reason I don't want it to go in my "MainActivity" is that I don't want these network calls to be called when ever i return to the MainActivity from another screen in the app, only when the user returns to the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case of calling whenever the app returns from background is by implementing Activity Life Cycle methods in your Application class:

```
    public class myApp extends Application implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    ...
    }
```

In this case you make sure that whenever an `onPause()` is called a corresponding `onResume()` should also be called (i.e. normal screen switching). If not, then you know that your app is now in background. The next callback to `onResume()` should mean that it has come to foreground again and you can make your network call.

Comment: are you aware of any downsides to doing this?

Comment: I used it in one of the internal apps. It worked as expected.

Comment: You can use Application class's `onCreated()` to make network call for when the app is killed and opened again (will also cover first run use case). I guess, that covers all you use cases?

Comment: what about if it is sent to the background and returned? dont think it will cover that case would it?

Comment: That was the use case my answer above covered. :)

Comment: yea im going to test that and will mark as the answer once i have done my testing. Thanks